# Text file data into a webpage for graphing

Tags: javascript, c#, database, web

I am new to web dev and I have a text file that I created using C# to collect some data from a website. Now I want to use that data to make graphs or some way to show the info on a website. Is it possible to use I/O in javascript or what is my best option here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: In JavaScript, you can do a AJAX GET request to load the file into memory if the text file is hosted on the same domain as the JavaScript. The jQuery library makes this task much easier. If you format your text file as a JSON object, then you can access the properties and values very easily or load the object into a charting library like Kendo or HighCharts.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options at your disposal:

1. Use a server-side technology (like ASP.Net, Node.js etc) to load, parse and display the file contents as HTML
2. Put the file on a web server and use AJAX to load and parse it. As @Quantastical suggested in his comment, convert the file to JSON forma for easir handling in Javascript.
3. Have the original program save the file in HTML format instead of text, and serve that page. You could just serve the txt file as is, but the user experience would be horrible.

Probably option 1 makes the most sense, with a combination of 1 + 2 to achieve some dynamic behavior the most recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in C# and ASP then one option is to render the html from the server without need for javascript.

In C# the `System.IO` namespace gives access to the `File` object.

```
String thetext = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

or

```
String[] thetextLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

or

If you have `JSON` or `Xml` in the file then you can also read and deserialize into an object for easier use.

When you have the text you can create the ASP/HTML elements with the data. A crude example would be:

```
HtmlGenericControl label = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
label.InnerHTML = theText;
Page.Controls.Add(label);
```

There are also `HTMLEncode` and `HTMLDecode` methods if you need them.

Of course that is a really crude example of loading the text at server and then adding Html to the Asp Page. Your question doesn't say where you want this processing to happen. Javascript might be better or a combination or C# and javascript.

Lastly to resolve a physical file path from a virtual path you can use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(virtualPath)`. A physical path is required to use the `File` methods shown above.